# transition not working on 1st scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, css-transitions

I have script for reduce height of logo when scrolling but I scroll for the first time transition for the logo not working. Everything else work fine. From the second time logo transition also start to work. I dont know what is the wrong. Please help I really appreciate it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    ypos = window.pageYOffset;

    var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
    var nav = document.getElementById('main_nav');
    var sm = document.getElementById('sm');
    var mm = document.getElementById('mm');
    var but = document.getElementById('tp-button');
    var but2 = document.getElementById('tp-button2');

    if (ypos > 1) {
        logo.style.height = '70px'
        nav.style.height = '70px'
        sm.style.marginTop = '13px'
        mm.style.marginTop = '5px'
    } else {
        logo.style.height = '107px'
        nav.style.height = '107px'
        sm.style.marginTop = '30px'
        mm.style.marginTop = '20px'
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ty2fjhhr/ here is the link to fiddle

Comment: Can you reproduce this on `jsfiddle.net`

Comment: where did `ypos = window.pageYOffset;` come from? where is `ypos` declared? And why not `$(window).pageYOffset;`? and a fiddle please!

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary It means that is `global`

Comment: @Tushar, I get that! I just wanted OP to share the more code and to confirm if there has been any changes to that variable befor hitting `.scroll()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ty2fjhhr/  here is the link to fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your javascript function

Demo Link : http://jsfiddle.net/ty2fjhhr/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function myCustomFunction()
{
    var ypos = window.pageYOffset;

    var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
    var nav = document.getElementById('main_nav');
    var sm = document.getElementById('sm');
    var mm = document.getElementById('mm');
    var but = document.getElementById('tp-button');
    var but2 = document.getElementById('tp-button2');

       if (ypos > 1) {
           logo.style.height = '70px'
           nav.style.height = '70px'
           sm.style.marginTop = '13px'
           mm.style.marginTop = '5px'
        } else {
           logo.style.height = '107px'
           nav.style.height = '107px'
           sm.style.marginTop = '30px'
           mm.style.marginTop = '20px'
        }
    }

    myCustomFunction();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
       myCustomFunction();
    });
});
```